# Menu is not displaying on the site navigation

Tags: menus, navigation

I am using Axis Wordpress theme. I have created a new page and added it to the menu. But when I visit to the site I am not able to see the menu navigation link. I don't see any page to navigate and no menu on the site. Am I missing something or I need to do something extra?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a menu, after adding your pages to it, and after saving once, you have to check the box at the bottom on the page to tell wordpress on which menu area of your theme you would like to add the menu. You can also assign menus in appearrance -> customize.

Comment: I have tried it but it didn't work. appearance -> menu I have marked Primary Navigation and in appearance -> customize also it shows primary navigation as my menu.